# Focusing assertions and actions with specific element

Tags: dalekjs

So, I am wondering if there is a way to focus in on a specific element and assert or act on elements within that elements node.

Example:

- board

  - Stack-1

    - post-1
    - post-2
  - Stack-2

    - post-1
    - post-2

I have a board with multiple stacks of items, we'll call them posts.  On each of theses posts there are multiple actions(links) that could be acted on e.g. like, comment, delete.  So the "like" link on each post has the same class name.

when doing the following, dalek just finds the first link with .like-button and clicks it:

```js
module.exports = {
'Checking Like click': function (test) {
  test
    .open('url')
    .click('.like-button')
    .done();
}
};
```

So, to the point, is there a way to focus in on a particular element and only utilize that elements selectors? Something like:

```js
module.exports = {
'Checking Like click': function (test) {
  test
    .open('url')
    .within('#stack-id')
        .within('#post-id')
            .click('.like-button')
        .end
    .end
    .done();
}
};
```

any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution to your problem is way simpler than you might have guessed. Dalek can chain selectors in the same way as your CSS files can do:

```
module.exports = {
'Checking Like click': function (test) {
  test
    .open('url')
    .click('#stack-id #post-id .like-button')
    .done();
}
};
```

This is all you need.